# LEETCODE #148 Sort List , runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

```
struct ListNode* sortList(struct ListNode* head){

    struct ListNode *temp, *change;
    int temp_data;
    temp = head;
    change = head->next;  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    while(temp)
    {
        change = temp->next;
        while(change)
        {
            if (temp->val > change->val)
            {
                temp_data = temp->val;
                temp->val = change->val;
                change->val = temp_data;
            }

            change = change->next;
        }



        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

[leetcode Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/)
`Given the head of a linked list, return the list after sorting it in ascending order.`

I have tried to write that same code in Dev c++, everything seems working.
In the code about I tried to make pointer change to point to the next node in head, and leetcode gave me an error:

```
Line 13: Char 12: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode' [solution.c]
```

What have caused that error? It not supposed to be error right?

Comment: One case that presumably must be handled is that of an empty list.  In that case, the `head` pointer passed into your function will be null.  If an error such as you describe is triggered by the line you have marked then that will be the reason.

Comment: And the program is erroneous in that case whether or not it crashes or reports a diagnostic.  Furthermore, it looks like you could simply remove that line altogether, because the function never reads the value written to `change` by it.  The later `change = temp->next` is performed before `change` is ever read.

Comment: You should [edit] and show a [mcve]. THen we can give you a more accurate answer.